# "No package wine available" and "No package fluxbox available"

Tags: centos, package-management, wine, fluxbox

I'm running "Centos 6 64-bit" on a Virtual Private Server (VPS) (i.e. on the cloud).

When I issue this command: "**yum install** vnc-server **wine** xterm **fluxbox** vsftpd firefox vnstat"

I get some results that all seem to be fine except:-

(...)
"No package wine available." 
(...)
"No package fluxbox available." 
(...)

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

This is my first time to use CentOS, and I've rarely used linux (Ubuntu) at all.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:**

1) To download the package as instructed, I presume this is the way to do it:-

```
wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

*Result (last line only):-*

```
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

2) I then executed this:-

```
rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
```

*Result:-*

```
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

3) Then:-

```
rpm -K rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.*.rpm
```

*Result:-*

```
rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm: (sha1) dsa sha1 md5 gpg OK
```

4) After that:-

```
rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.*.rpm
```

*Result:-*

```
package rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64 is already installed
```

5) Installing Fluxbox:-

```
yum install fluxbox
```

*Result:-*

```
No package flusbox available.
Error: Nothing to do
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

Steps from http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge#head-f0c3ecee3dbb407e4eed79a56ec0ae92d1398e01

**EDIT 2:-**
By the way, I did the following before all of this (as suggested in a tutorial):-

Copy & paste the following into the Extra.repo file:

```
[dag]
name=Dag RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1

[kbs-CentOS-Extras]
name=CentOS.Karan.Org-EL$releasever - Stable
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://centos.karan.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-karan.org.txt
enabled=1
baseurl=http://centos.karan.org/el$releasever/extras/stable/$basearch/RPMS/

[kbs-CentOS-Misc]
name=CentOS.Karan.Org-EL$releasever - Stable
gpgkey=http://centos.karan.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-karan.org.txt
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
baseurl=http://centos.karan.org/el$releasever/misc/stable/$basearch/RPMS/
```

Save & exit. (Then:-)

```
# rpm --import http://centos.karan.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-karan.org.txt
# rpm --import http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
# yum update
```

Comment: Please add the contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CentOS 5, the fluxbox package was available in the RPMForge repo.  But the CentOS 6 version of the RPMForge repo does not currently include fluxbox.
The [EPEL](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repo for CentOS 6 **does** include fluxbox.

```
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
yum install fluxbox
```

`wine` does remain available from the RPMForge repo in CentOS 6.

Comment: I think I've done that! I tried -ivh -Uvh with the two repos, but it didn't work... anyway, it did work now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The packages you are getting the warnings about do not exist in the standard CentOS yum repo. You will need some 3rd party repos. You will want to be careful when adding new repo's, the good repo vendors ensure packages do not break each other, however there is some sloppy repo's out there.

I recommend checking [Elrepo](http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php) and [RPMforge](http://repoforge.org/) repos first for the packages you are missing.

CentOS Wiki about 3rd party repo's: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/

Comment: Are the repos small in size? They took few seconds to install. I still get "No package wine available." and "No package fluxbox available." What can I do?  EDIT: Oh, I forgot checking if they contain the packages. I'll see and report back.

Comment: RPMforge contains fluxbox. I use rpm -ivh and -Uvh, and I still get "No package fluxbox available."

Comment: If they are not in elrepo or rpmforge, check that CentOS wiki page for a list of other recommended repos.

Comment: Assuming that you installed RPMforge, did you also enable it? Full directions are here: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge

Comment: I'll edit my initial question for clarity.

Comment: You probably need to run `yum update` to pull in the list of new packages provided by the new repo.

Answer (score 1):

The EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repo for CentOS 6 includes fluxbox.

The new URL is:

http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

So you need to:

```
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install fluxbox
```

Comment: This also worked to make the package available on RHEL6